# Initialize member array at compile time

Tags: c++, c++20, metaprogramming, constexpr, compile-time

Is it possible to initialize the idx value of the array_object at compile time such that `member_array[0].idx = 0;` `member_array[1].idx = 1;` ... `member_array[array_size-1].idx = array_size-1`. The value member of every `array_object` should be initialized with an empty string literal.

```
struct my_class {
    struct array_object {
        int idx;
        std::string value{};
    };
    static constexpr size_t array_size = /* some compile time constant*/;

    std::array<array_object, array_size> member_array = /* default initialize where idx of each array_object is +1 of the preceeding array_object
                                                        and the first array_object idx is 0 ; array_object value always initialized to empty string*/;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you just do it as usual in the constructor, and slap `constexpr` onto the constructor.

Comment: Not unless it’s a static member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you make you inner struct `constexpr` constructible and `constexpr` copyable.

UPD: Apparently, it doesn't work on GCC. However, it works on Clang and MSVC. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAKykAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn6BdpgOWQ1NBCWRMXEJyQqNza15HeP9YYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2Bbk3ETACeJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenY8RhwDd3jw8A9P9DgBJAiHPAKQ5oFgpOivRxsKECMaGMEEBBMAi/QFI2GYdDgwSoQ40GoEgBuYi8mAAdL8CJgYQYGW83ARLilGKxXqDGaRDhkAF6YAD6YI8XkEPweYVocyRDDGmFUKWIAoI6BAIHOVxObl5LH5Eql/mwUIAsoyKsCGIQ3gARY6JKyJe0QJbHADsVgeh3Vmu1xAu11OBqNaxNZuImAUJx99z9/DVECForBeAdhw0cfBrMOxqx/gsx0s1jwHpM3t%2Bfr90djzrwJldNLw6FUmcbRerXvt3ejBHWDEOdbjv0rbqWo4evw%2BXgchxYlxF%2ByYCkhlfjftn851S9Q0W0XTBG%2B7frC6bbJ89va7vprYwDHy%2Bh0p3kwV5vm5raEVDJVat3EV90PBx3UzLAqCYLxaELL8/R/JV/0OQDgKPCAELBFCDyPcwADYK38R0IKgmCpwTHsyK3RpHGQBVENVAU8GFMVkKDK4RVTTNPUo/0tV3PUsJAgh%2BUA1MbgXK04hFXcHVPb9LQWYgbUIAS2L3bCHBEtSOKY99TTI8c4w4FZaE4RJeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrAFNYNleHYeFIAhNGMlYAGsAkkGlJEkLhcP8T1/H8DQAA5PSST19E4SQLK8mzOF4BQQA0DyvJWOBYBgRAUFQGE4TICh0OK2F6HiFcjC4T0NC4Pg6AZYgMogaIUuiMImkuTh3O65hiEuAB5DTPO4XhoTYQQRoYWg%2Bqs3gsGiLxgDOWhaAyybSCwFhDGAcQlt2vBo26ckYxS5Uui8Bl%2Bt4c8ahSuVoguYaPCwe6PM%2BFh7pWKgDGABQADU8EwAB3EbOUs9z%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUY7dECAwjBQBzLH0PBogyyAVlQFI6kVTgAFoHxOe1TFLSwzGs1ALqDVtLtJ6paiyFwGHcTw2j0EI5jKCo9DSDJKcmPwmqlooGAGcXhiazpunqGZZb0dXKd6ZplaGeI1a1oW8hNvpDcUiQVgUZzNhthKOHM0hLNZzhDlUKLcOp3DJChHHgEOeqaQ0GkuEOCBcEIEgS38Lgll4CatCWXyAi4GlcIargNFwgBOSREg0PP/DzrhscS3hfoimkIrr%2BuG9w12Utsjh0sy7KltygqICQaEqrichKH70qQGAcuzGamC4nazrjsG3qvoX4axqEr7psYAg5oWlKVrWjatq%2BvaDqO6z8DOxwLu26zruQW6tncx7TOOl63suD6H6Tn6/r4QGQbByG0Mvpw2EKIcQyMQFozUClXQTVA54yZjYF6JN3Q2QplkbatMNT00ZlYZmrN2afCwCg22NQjx8wgK4bWTVRalCNpLQoMszZywKNLLIVsJZqzIRrBg%2BsWjMJ1twvWMwOGq1sKbXILCUQGzFvQhOqx1gO3kc/F2bteCt09t7X2/tgDIFouXGkZhI7RyIGqNyidO4pxWAgTATAsDxFQc/JKpBq7%2BFrg3DxEUm5qNSm3WwHdk7GVIHlQqI9qpDwqiVaqIByTIBSCkEU5IuB5xFP4KKIovZNxoNPNqlA57WWXotAaPUV7jXXsVGaW95qLTPpgVa60xCHx2sfIwp9lqnXIVfK6qgbp3R2k/Z6RM34fy%2BgQb%2Bk1/p/1BhDKGjBgGyARuA6QkClDQMxgkfQB0EF4KQUTEhaDKbbX%2BA%2BbZ1gWbqMIZzfZusKFUIETQgWojjasMVtQl5lMnmCN5prPobybk/JkXQ62FsJj3PEZbWRwLbb2yRiZMyyVjoaMyQuBQsSXzJNrlFYx%2BBTFxwTknHKcKODONce4zxjdm6IrSv4rKgTU6kD8vHTO2dc4FyLiXMuFcOD%2BARe7PxdLgk9x7kgNYBAUi3QiWEuIERuScEydow4uj9FuLMLwfEMciF6BAYspGyzZBQIxtZWBpBwYXBSD/FRvL1GcBGrdcVYJUBUE0T7P2iq9HBxVZHDwUS4h4osXS6xtj7GUCJSSkARdKV8vbrSnKgr4C9xAKK%2B1krKqlRlWwTgxAvBjH0TST0iRQ5qpxSQVsWqFlgN1SjeQqzDU6HyKapg5qJlO1US3G1drbqHEdc6hVtUg4hzDhHCA3qB5mLMBFf1hKGUBDcVFOdSREixUkBoCKiQuVhojT41u0bLHeWnTXOdUUF1LpXf4NdTseWRutfyqdz9VVXt8QSruKx2YZGcJIIAA%3D)

```cpp
// It is compile time constant that
// copied into field value.
template <typename Item, size_t Count>
inline constexpr std::array<Item, Count> cMemberInit = []() {
  std::array<Item, Count> res;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < Count; ++i) {
    res[i].idx = i;
  }
  return res;
}();

struct my_class {
  struct array_object {
    int idx{};
    std::string value{};
    constexpr array_object() = default;
    constexpr array_object(const array_object&) = default;
  };
  static constexpr size_t array_size = 7;
  std::array<array_object, array_size> member_array =
      cMemberInit<array_object, array_size>;
};
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't know. It works on Clang and I have tested using it. It is possible that GCC just didn't implemented some part of C++20 standard yet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an immediately-invoked `constexpr` lambda (note `consteval` works in gcc trunk but not 13.2 yet, so I've left it off and leaned on the implicit `constexpr operator()` in the lambda instead).

```
struct my_class {
    struct array_object {
        int idx;
        std::string value{};
    };
    static constexpr size_t array_size = 5/* some compile time constant*/;

    std::array<array_object, array_size> member_array
    = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::array<array_object, array_size>{array_object{Is}...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<array_size>{});
}
```

Test with `static_assert`:

```
    static_assert(0 == my_class{}.member_array[0].idx);
    static_assert(1 == my_class{}.member_array[1].idx);
    static_assert(2 == my_class{}.member_array[2].idx);
    static_assert(3 == my_class{}.member_array[3].idx);
    static_assert(4 == my_class{}.member_array[4].idx);
```

### [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rTxxae3rc) (clang, gcc, msvc)